# The right Way to instantiate xserver-xorg-video-dummy driver at boot time for CRON scheduled WINE app

Tags: 18.04, wine, cron

The context: I have a Windows based apps provided by a data service provider. I have managed to get this to work in WINE. The app requires a GUI (initial configuration, login credentials and exception data management) for initial and adhoc tasks. I configured remote RDP into tightvncserver/xfce4. It works well.

I need to schedule data updates (multiple times per day). However the app does require a GUI environment so I setup the headless display manager (xserver-xorg-video-dummy driver). From a terminal I can manually start "X &" and then instantiate the windows app. Loving Ubuntu so far :)
...
DISPLAY=:0 wine start C:\MyUpdater.exe update=1 close=1
...
However I need to schedule this via cron under a normal user. I believe I should only start X only once (to maintain the correct headless DISPLAY=:0 ref).

I am a big fan of doing things right and am wondering on the correct way to set this up so X starts on boot but is accessible by the crontask.

A pointer would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Lex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start headless X on boot:

```
sudo /var/systemd/system/headlessx.service
```

With content:

[Unit]
Description=Headless X server
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/X
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Then test/install:

Start it:
    sudo systemctl start headlessx

Enable it to run at boot:
    sudo systemctl enable headlessx

Stop it:
    sudo systemctl stop headlessx

Hope this helps someone. Running my windows GUI based app from the command line works a treat. Now if only I could make is work as a cron task life would be perfect. ;)